# Grabbing an ordered createdAt set from two different tables in a relational DB (ie. MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

The deal is as follows:

Lets say I have 2 tables, Articles and Projects. The share some columns but are substantially different beasts.

I need to grab the 7 most recently published of either Articles or Projects. Then, even more frustratingly, I'm going to want to grab the next 7, and then again the next 7 with a provided offset.

What's the best course of action? Is there way to query the DB in such a way as to return an amalgamated result set that'll allow me to easily offset by 7 to grab the next 7? There's gotta be something more clever than, say, keeping track of the createdAt date or some other malarky.

Comment: What is your result set going to look like?  SQL queries have pre-defined columns, so the columns need to be the same for the two tables.

Comment: That's a fair point and kind of what I'm trying to figure. I'm wondering if I can return a set of IDs and createdAt dates that are somehow marked as an Article or a Project, you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested code, but the following query (if there are no typos) should provide you with the firs seven needed elements.

```
select id, createdAt, data_type
from ((select id, createdAt, 'Article' as data_type
       from Article)
      union
      (select id, createdAt, 'Project' as data_type
       from Project)) MyTable
order by createdAt desc
limit 0, 7
```

EDIT:

You can also make it a single request, by using what I have given above as a subquery and joining left to the Article and Project tables and using the needed values with the help of case when.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want ids, then that is easy:

```
select 'Article' as which, ArticleId as id, CreatedAt
from Articles
union all
select 'Project', ProjectId, CreatedAt
from Projects
order by CreatedAt desc
limit 7;
```

To prevent ties, you should probably use:

```
order by CreatedAt desc, which, id;
```

Comment: Nice one, published slightly before my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Works not half bad, had to modify it a little to return what I was needing. @LajosArpad had a better out of the box answer so he gets the accepted answer this time.

Comment: @romanchukenator . . . I would be very careful with the potential of identical `CreatedAt` dates, and you should definitely use `union all` instead of `union`, unless you don't care at all about performance.